# Capturar varias lineas de un string en c++

Tags: c++, string

Tengo una duda un tanto peculiar creo.

Estoy programando un analizador lexico en c++ y necesito capturar un codigo por el usuario:

Ejemplo:

```
int main(){

    cout << "mi programa";

    return 0;
}
```

Si utilizo `getline();` en un `string` se guarda lo siguiente:

```
int main(){
```

¿De qué forma puedo almacenar todo el código en un `string` o bien cuál es la forma correcta/sugerencia de abordar esto?

Comment: Me parece una pregunta un tanto abierta. Dinos tú qué método quieres usar para identificar el final del código. Mediante algún carácter en particular quizá? Las formas más simples de lectura son usando la función [`read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) y [`get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

Comment: Utilizas `getline` ¿sobre qué? ¿sobre la entrada de consola? ¿sobre un flujo de archivo?